# Kubernetes not starting in docker for Mac

Tags: macos, kubernetes

I am running docker for Mac in latest Mojave. Tried to enable Kubernetes from the preferences. Since then the message is just 'kubernetes is starting'. But it never completes. I am confused as to what has to be done.
Is there anything that I need to change in the network config part?

Just before this, I tried a failed attempt of installing Minikube in the same machine.

Comment: I had the same issue and could fix it with the following procedure.
Go to Preferences - Reset - Reset Kubenetes Cluster and Reset Disk Image.
This solved it for me...

Comment: Tried reset as suggested but doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 4):

For me was very useful:

1. stop docker for desktop
2. remove the folder `~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker/pki`

```
   rm -rf ~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker/pki
```

3. start docker for destkop

Found [the solution here](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/3594#issuecomment-621487150)

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue on MacOS Catalina. Resetting to factory defaults did finally resolve the issue for me.

Select Troubleshoot from the drop down menu or preferences and click the bug. Then select Reset to factory defaults.

Obviously this is a destructive solution, so use with care.

[image: Troubleshoot:Reset to factory defaults]

Answer (score 1):

thats did it for me

```
rm -rf ~/.kube
```